# Options except Parse.com for EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

Hi is there any good option for Parse.com for backend

I need support for emberJs as parse ember adapter is not complete.
[github by clintjhill](https://github.com/clintjhill/ember-parse-adapter)

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you don't want to build your own adapter (which is the recommended way) to deal with parse.com's API peculiarities, you could use the [ember-parse-adapter](https://github.com/clintjhill/ember-parse-adapter) you mentioned and extending it to your needs.

Hope it helps.